# Creating a file of a specific size with incrementing alphabets/numbers in python.

Tags: python, file-io

How to create a file of a specific size (say 1024bytes) and each line should have a number or alphabet in an incrementing order. The total size of the file should not exceed 1024 bytes(even after putting alphabets/numbers in it).

I tried this

```
def create_file_numbers(filename, size):
    f=open(filename,"wb")
    for x in range(size):
        f.write(str(x))
        f.write('\r\n')
    f.close()
    pass
```

But this creates a file of size much greater than 1024 having numbers 1 to 1023.
I am a beginner in python so explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string representation of a number is larger than just the number, typically one, two, or four bytes for each character. Your `\r` and `\n` take up that space too.

```
max_len = max_size / bytes_per_char
s = ''
i = 0
while len(s) < max_len:
    s += str(i) + '\r\n'
    i += 1
if len(s) > max_len: # because it may not divide evenly
    s = s[:max_len]
open(filename, "wb").write(s)
```

Comment: Then how can i fill the file with incremented number in each line? and without using \r\n how can i move to the next line?

Comment: You can have all of that. But you can't do 1024 iterations and expect 1024 bytes. You need a lot fewer numbers.

Comment: Yes i know that and that is what is the major issue. How to make the file of 1024 bytes with an incrementing number on each line.

Comment: This works fine but how much shoulld i set bytes_per_char if i want to enter only numbers in incrementing order.

Comment: it's a question of file encoding. typical string would probably be 1, but i defer to someone else to truly answer that

Comment: When i try your code it works fine but the last line contains 226. I want the last line to end with '\r\n'. How should i do that?? I tried "s+='\r\n'" after while loop but it didn't work.

Comment: Honestly I'd just go with @jterrance's answer instead

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Define your string of characters:

```
import string
alphabet = string.digits + string.ascii_letters
```

Then replace:

```
f.write(str(x))
```

with:

```
f.write(alphabet[x % len(alphabet)])
```

For example:

```
>>> import string
>>> alphabet = string.digits + string.ascii_letters
>>> ' '.join(alphabet[x % len(alphabet)] for x in range(200))
'0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d'
```

Comment: and when x+87 gets above 127?

Comment: @AShelly OP didn't specify size range - this should be enough to get started

Answer (score 1):

The only tricky thing about this is that numbers have increasing numbers of digits as they get larger. You can avoid that by padding with zeroes to make each line the same size. For example, let's make each line 8 bytes long. The `'\r\n'` takes up two, leaving 6 for the digits, and that's more than enough.

```
for n in range(1024/8):
    f.write('%06d\r\n' % n)
```

To get exactly 1024 bytes without padding, you won't be able to start at 0 or 1. A line with a single digit takes three bytes, two digits takes four bytes, and three digits takes five. 1024 / 5 = 204 remainder 4, so you want 204 lines with three-digit numbers and one with a two-digit number. The two-digit number has to be 99 so that the next number will have three digits. So this works:

```
for n in range(99, 304):
    f.write('%d\r\n' % n)
```

Comment: even if i try that the size becomes more than 1024. it becomes 1280 bytes.

Comment: Yes, that's because I typed "8" where I meant "6"! Fixed now.

Comment: That works perfect. Thanks :) But isn't there any way by which i can avoid padding but still get the desired file.